# RxJS - concat and merge two observables

Tags: rxjs

I've got two Observables

```
public readonly availableTags$ = this.tagSandbox.observeTags()
public readonly jobs$ = this.jobSandbox.observeJobsAfterFiltering()
```

which I use as `Input` values for an Angular component with an `async` pipe.

I'd like to transform these two observable in a single one and "merge" their values in single object.

```
{
   availableTags: Tag[],
   jobs: Job[]
}
```

However, the value from `jobs$` should be fetched only after `availableTags$` has emitted its value.
Is that possible?

All this is to avoid a "double reload" of the Input properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `concatMap` for this (`mergeMap` will work as well) and then map the response from the second call together with the result of the first call into a single object:

```
availableTags$.pipe(
  concatMap(availableTags => jobs$.pipe(
    map(jobs => ({ availableTags, jobs })),
  ))
);
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. What about using Zip?

Comment: `zip` emits only when all source Observables emit the same number of items but you said you want to run `jobs$` after `availableTags$`.

Comment: You're right! What if instead of only one, I need to fetch multiple values after availableTags? I'd use this concatMap and combineLatest for the multiple observables, sounds good to you?

Comment: Then instead of returning just `jobs$` you can return `forkJoin(jobs$, other1$, other2$, ...)` and `forkJoin` will emit only when all its source Observables emit at least once and complete.

Comment: Problem is those Observables never complete, they're part of the Redux state management